# Passing value from select box to if statement to change content in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, if-statement, foreach

i'm not sure how to go about this but what I need to happen is when a new option is selected in the select box at the top of the XSL is for the displayed EP to change by changing the value of the @id that is required for the IF test further down the XML. I thought I would maybe be able to do this by using the value of the select box?

Here is my XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="imagefolder" select="'xml/images/'" />
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<body>
<xsl:element name="select">
<xsl:for-each select="dalehoward/ep"> 
<xsl:element name="option">
<xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="name"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:element> 
<br /><br />
<table border="1px"  bordercolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%">
  <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
    <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Year</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Label</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Artwork</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Tracks / Player</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="dalehoward/ep">
  <xsl:sort select="year" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
  <xsl:if test="@id = 1">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="label"/></td>
    <td><img width="150px" height="150px"><xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$imagefolder"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="image"/>
    </xsl:attribute></img></td>
    <td><xsl:for-each select="track">
    <xsl:if test="../@id = 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>.
    <xsl:value-of select="tname"/><br />
    <xsl:value-of select="length"/> <br /><br />

    <xsl:element name="iframe">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">cf</xsl:attribute>  
    <xsl:attribute name="width">440</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="height">260</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">http://www.youtube.com/embed/<xsl:value-of select="ytubelink"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="frameborder">0</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:comment/>
</xsl:element> <br /><br />

        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my XML:

```
<dalehoward>
<bio>
<profilepic>profilepic.jpg</profilepic>
<dob>16/10/1987</dob>
<pob>Liverpool</pob>
<about>
English Deep House producer Dale Howard first burst onto the scene in 2009 with his debut EP on Neurotraxx Deluxe Gotta Be Deep, which topped the Beatport Deep House chart reaching the Number 1 spot. Since then he has been making waves with an array of releases on world renowned labels like Fear Of Flying, Loco Records and many others. Aswell as having countless top 20's and 50's Dale has also reached Number 2 and Number 3 on the Beatport Deep House Chart with his tracks 'Dropout' and 4 Hour Bang, which also stayed in the Top 10 for 9 weeks. In 2010 Dale launched his own imprint Static Audio, which is a hotbed for established and up and coming Deep and Tech House producers alike and features some of the biggest Deep House artists in the world. With his productions having support from artists like Richie Hawtin, Nic Fancuilli, Mark Knight, Florian Meindl, Funkagenda, Karol XVII and MB Valence, Ekkohaus, Robert Owens, Filthy Rich, Ronan Portela, Soul Miniority and a load more, Dale continues to make Top notch Deep House and has forthcoming releases on even more of the worlds finest House labels.
</about>
</bio>
<ep id="1">
    <name>Letters EP</name>
    <year>2012</year>
    <label>Static Audio</label>
    <image>letters.jpg</image>

        <track number="1" beatportrank="0">
            <tname>Letters</tname>
            <length>6.35</length>
            <ytubelink>2H2XDQqvbpc</ytubelink>
        </track>
        <track number="2" beatportrank="0">
            <tname>Later</tname>
            <length>7.56</length>
            <ytubelink>w61RrgBPahk</ytubelink>
        </track>
            <track number="3" beatportrank="0">
            <tname>'89 Flava</tname>
            <length>7:38</length>
            <ytubelink>Mgarl-FlVhQ</ytubelink>
        </track>
        <track number="4" beatportrank="0">
            <tname>Safe Presentation</tname>
            <length>7.55</length>
            <ytubelink>d_U38G9AwHk</ytubelink>
        </track>
</ep>



<ep id="2">
    <name>Inner City EP</name>
    <year>2012</year>
    <label>Lost My Dog</label>
    <image>innercity.jpg</image>

    <track number="1" beatportrank="0">
            <tname>C'Mon</tname>
            <length>7.15</length>
            <ytubelink>Y9ExPTumGg4</ytubelink>
        </track>
        <track number="2" beatportrank="0">
            <tname>Koppabird</tname>
            <length>6.27</length>
            <ytubelink>RrSgPq9gw9E</ytubelink>
        </track>
        <track number="3" beatportrank="0">
            <tname>Inner City</tname>
            <length>8:50</length>
            <ytubelink>zuABxrp5A2U</ytubelink>
        </track>
        <track number="4" beatportrank="0">
            <tname>You Can</tname>
            <length>8:16</length>
            <ytubelink>oxFynevJf6Y</ytubelink>
        </track>
</ep>
<ep id="3">
    <name>Some Other Guy EP</name>
    <year>2012</year>
    <label>OFF</label>
    <image>someotherguy.jpg</image>

    <track number="1" beatportrank="8">
            <tname>Some Other Guy</tname>
            <length>8:04</length>
            <ytubelink>xY9Xr5YVDmY</ytubelink>
        </track>
        <track number="2" beatportrank="0">
            <tname>No Need</tname>
            <length>8:04</length>
            <ytubelink>q9Qi3NziI98</ytubelink>
        </track>
        <track number="3" beatportrank="7">
            <tname>Trickster</tname>
            <length>7:26</length>
            <ytubelink>WOEMRPmNqF8</ytubelink>
        </track>
        <track number="4" beatportrank="0">
            <tname>District</tname>
            <length>8:34</length>
            <ytubelink>Dbi17vfja6s</ytubelink>
        </track>
</ep>
</dalehoward>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear on what you are trying to do in the example above but I think you are looking for the `position()` function. It returns the position of the current node in the current node set (position of the first node is 1).

You can use it like-

```
<xsl:for-each select="dalehoward/ep">

<option value="{position()}"></option>

<!-- OR -->

<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>

<!-- OR -->

<xsl:if test="position() &gt; 5">
<!-- DO SOMETHING -->
</xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Your right option is definitley want I want. Once I have stored the position() as the value of the option box, how can I later use that same value in another loop?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far as well :)

Comment: You can store the value of position in a xsl:variable and then use it in the next loop. Can you update the question with input XML and the output you are looking for?

Comment: Hey apologies if it was vague, I have now updated the question, thanks again